# javaScript - porject of calculator income and expenses - removing specific object by click but keep the rest

Tags: javascript

I got a project to build income and expenses calculator. i stored everything (income and expenses in seperate array of objects) and i am stuck in problem - every object in the array contain two properties - description and value . the question is how can i remove only specific one by clicking it , if two of the same kind has been inserted (both their description and value are same);

```
// Header Reference
const balanceNumber = document.querySelector('.balance__number');
const incomeNumber = document.querySelector('.income__number');
const expensesNumber = document.querySelector('.expenses__number');

// form Reference
const selectedSigns = document.querySelector('#selection__sign');
const inputDescription = document.querySelector('#input__description-value');
const inputNumber = document.querySelector('#input__number-value');
const checkButtn = document.querySelector('.fa-check-circle');

// List Reference
const ulIncomeList = document.querySelector('.income__list ul');
const ulExpList = document.querySelector('.expenses__list ul');
let liInc;
let liExp;

let counterInc = 0;
let counterExp = 0;

// Variables
let arrayObjIncome = [], arrayObjExp = [], sumIncome = 0, sumExp = 0 , sumTotal = 0;

//--------------------------------------------------------------

// Funcions that create li, div and span template (one for Income list, one for Exp list)

const liAndSpanIncomeTemp = ()=> {
    let liAndSpanTempInc = `<li class = 'IncLi'> <span>${inputDescription.value.trim()}</span> <div class = 'inner__div'> <span>+ ${inputNumber.value}</span> <span><i class="far fa-times-circle circle-green"></i></span> </div> </li>`;
    ulIncomeList.innerHTML += liAndSpanTempInc
};

const liAndSpanExpTemp = ()=> {
    let liAndSpanTempExp = `<li class = 'ExpLi'> <span>${inputDescription.value.trim()}</span> <div class = 'inner__div'> <span>- ${inputNumber.value}</span> <span><i class="far fa-times-circle circle-red"></i></span> </div> </li>`;
    ulExpList.innerHTML += liAndSpanTempExp
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------

// Function that Calculate sum

const sumFn = (arrayOfObj, sum) => {
    arrayOfObj.forEach(obj => {
        sum += obj.value;
    });
    return sum;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------

// Adding to List => Add EventListner to the check button 

checkButtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {

    if (selectedSigns.value == '+' && inputDescription.value.length > 0 && inputNumber.value > 0) {
        counterInc++
        liAndSpanIncomeTemp();
        liInc = document.querySelectorAll('.IncLi');
        // push data inside the array obj Inc
        arrayObjIncome.push({description: inputDescription.value , value : Number(inputNumber.value) , percentage: undefined});

        // Calc sum Inc and Put in the DOM
        incomeNumber.innerHTML = `+ ${sumFn(arrayObjIncome, sumIncome)}`

    } else if (selectedSigns.value == '-' && inputDescription.value.length > 0 && inputNumber.value > 0) {
        counterExp++
        liAndSpanExpTemp();
        liExp = document.querySelectorAll('.ExpLi');
        // push data inside the array obj Exp
        arrayObjExp.push({description: inputDescription.value , value : Number(inputNumber.value), percentage: undefined});

        // Calc sum Exp and Put in the DOM
        expensesNumber.innerHTML = `- ${sumFn(arrayObjExp, sumExp)}`;
    }

    // Calc total sum and Put in the DOM
    sumTotal = sumFn(arrayObjIncome, sumIncome) - sumFn(arrayObjExp, sumExp);

    sumTotal > 0 ? balanceNumber.innerHTML = `+ ${sumTotal}` : balanceNumber.innerHTML = sumTotal
});


//--------------------------------------------------------------

// Removing from List => Add EventListner to the IncomeList 

ulIncomeList.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('circle-green')) {
        counterInc--
        let LiThatRemoved = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        let deletedDescriptionInc = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        let deletedNumberInc = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;

        deletedNumberInc = deletedNumberInc.split(" ");
        deletedNumberInc = Number(deletedNumberInc[1]);

        // Removing from li Inc - NodeList
        liInc = Array.from(liInc)
        for (let i=0; i<liInc.length; i++) {
            if (liInc[i] == LiThatRemoved) {
                liInc.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        // Removing from the array obj Inc
        for (let i=0; i< arrayObjIncome.length; i++) {
            if (arrayObjIncome[i].description === deletedDescriptionInc && arrayObjIncome[i].value === deletedNumberInc) {
                arrayObjIncome.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        // Calc sum Inc after removing and put in the DOM
        incomeNumber.innerHTML = `+ ${sumFn(arrayObjIncome, sumIncome)}`;
    }

    // Calc total sum and Put in the DOM
    sumTotal = sumFn(arrayObjIncome, sumIncome) - sumFn(arrayObjExp, sumExp);

    sumTotal > 0 ? balanceNumber.innerHTML = `+ ${sumTotal}` : balanceNumber.innerHTML = sumTotal;
});

//--------------------------------------------------------------

// Removing from List => Add EventListner to the ExpList

ulExpList.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('circle-red')) {
        counterExp--
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        let deletedDescriptionExp = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        let deletedNumberExp = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;

        deletedNumberExp = deletedNumberExp.split(" ");
        deletedNumberExp = Number(deletedNumberExp[1]);

        // Removing from the array obj Exp
        for (let i=0; i<arrayObjExp.length; i++) {
            if (arrayObjExp[i].description === deletedDescriptionExp && arrayObjExp[i].value === deletedNumberExp) {
                arrayObjExp.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        // Calc sum Exp after removing and put in the DOM
        expensesNumber.innerHTML = `- ${sumFn(arrayObjExp, sumExp)}`;
    }

    // Calc total sum and Put in the DOM
    sumTotal = sumFn(arrayObjIncome, sumIncome) - sumFn(arrayObjExp, sumExp);

    sumTotal > 0 ? balanceNumber.innerHTML = `+ ${sumTotal}` : balanceNumber.innerHTML = sumTotal;
});
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in your question as a code snippet so that we can re-create your issue and provide a working answer.

Comment: i am new to this form and progrmamming  so i dont know how to do  code snippet. can you explain how to do ?